# How to Delete All Registry Keys without Being Stopped by One Undeletable Key?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, registry

Is it possible to delete all registry keys that can be deleted without being stopped by one undeletable key using C#?

When you use the Registry Editor GUI to delete keys and you delete a subkey tree with undeletable keys inside it (e.g. key in use, insufficient permission), it will try to delete what it can without the undeletable keys stopping the operation.

This does not seem to be the case with the `Microsoft.Win32` library in C#.

Using an external program like reg.exe works, but I'm trying to look for a solution that does not require an external application.

```
private void DelHKLM()
        {
            try
            {
                using (RegistryKey desiredKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE", true))
                {
                    desiredKey.DeleteSubKeyTree("Policies");
                }
            }
        }
```

The anticipated result is for the program to not give any exceptions and delete the subkey tree "Policies", but instead, it throws an `UnauthorizedAccessException` because the keys are in use.

Note: I am running my program as Administrator and I do have permissions to the key as demonstrated through the registry editor.

So, my question is: **Is there any way to achieve what the Registry Editor does in C#, preferably using native libraries?**

Comment: What possible legitimate reason could there be to delete all keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SHDeleteKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-shdeletekeyw) works for me (tested on Windows 10) =>

```
UIntPtr hKey;               
int nStatus = RegOpenKeyEx((UIntPtr)HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, @"SOFTWARE", 0, DELETE | KEY_READ | KEY_WRITE | KEY_WOW64_64KEY, out hKey);
if (nStatus == 0)
{
    SHDeleteKey(hKey, @"Policies");
    RegCloseKey(hKey);
}
```

With declarations :

```
    [DllImport("Advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern int RegOpenKeyEx(UIntPtr hKey, string lpSubKey, int ulOptions, int samDesired, out UIntPtr phkResult);

    [DllImport("Advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern int RegCloseKey(UIntPtr hKey);

    [DllImport("Shlwapi.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern int SHDeleteKey(UIntPtr hKey, string pszSubKey);

    public const uint HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = 0x80000002;

    public const int READ_CONTROL = 0x00020000;
    public const int SYNCHRONIZE = 0x00100000;

    public const int STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ = READ_CONTROL;
    public const int STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE = READ_CONTROL;

    public const int KEY_QUERY_VALUE = 0x0001;
    public const int KEY_SET_VALUE = 0x0002;
    public const int KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY = 0x0004;
    public const int KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS = 0x0008;
    public const int KEY_NOTIFY = 0x0010;
    public const int KEY_CREATE_LINK = 0x0020;
    public const int KEY_READ = ((STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ |
                                                       KEY_QUERY_VALUE |
                                                       KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS |
                                                       KEY_NOTIFY)
                                                      &
                                                      (~SYNCHRONIZE));

    public const int KEY_WRITE = ((STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE |
                                                       KEY_SET_VALUE |
                                                       KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY)
                                                      &
                                                      (~SYNCHRONIZE));
    public const int KEY_WOW64_64KEY = 0x0100;
    public const int KEY_WOW64_32KEY = 0x0200;

    public const int DELETE = 0x00010000;
```